# Issue with uploading image using this.form.submit();

Tags: php, html, sql

I am using this.form.submit(); in order to upload an image straight after it is sellected and also pass some other info along.

I am having an issue, the submit works and passes the id with post but the image is not uploaded and the name is not inserted in the db it might add a name like 0_ but that is incorrect as well as the image name does not exist in the table so it should pass the if(file_exists) without any loops.

Any ideas on that?

```
<form id='image_upload' name='image_upload' action='customer_logo.php' method='post'>
    <input type="hidden" name='id' id='id' value='<?php echo $cust_id; ?>'>
    <input type='text' style="background-color:#93CD60; border-radius: 5px; color:white; font-size:17px; width:140px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer;" id='image_text' name='image_text' value="Add Logo"> </input>
    <input type='file' name='image' id='image' style='visibility: hidden'  accept="image/*" onchange="this.form.submit();" />
</form>
```

And the php code is the following:

```
if (isset ($_POST['image'])) {
    $cust_id = $_POST['id'];
    $images = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $imageSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

    if (!is_dir('img/logotipa/'.$cust_id)){
        mkdir('img/logotipa/'.$cust_id, 0777, true);
    }

    $upload_dir = 'img/logo/'.$cust_id.'/';
    $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($images,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
    $up_image = $images;

    if (file_exists($upload_dir.$images)){
        $counter = 0;
        
        while (file_exists($upload_dir.$up_image)){
            $up_image = $counter.'_'.$images;
            $counter++;            
        }

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir.$images);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO logos(customer_id, logo) VALUES (:ucid, :upic)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':ucid', $cust_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':upic',  $up_image);

        if ($stmt->execute()){
            echo '<script>window.location.href = "customer_logo.php";</script>';
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to add enctype to your `<form>` tag. i.e. `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. See https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the `<form>` element to specify the proper encoding for file uploads. And you probably want to check for `!empty($_FILES)` instead of `isset($_POST['image'])`. Also, you've defined an array of whitelisted extensions, but you're not doing anything with it (and beware of the typo in the variable name -> extensions *).

Comment: After I added the enctype it seems to be uploading the image but, no table input is created and the file after the 100% is not in the folder it is supposed to be. It must be something so stupid that i can not see.. @RoAchterberg

Comment: It really was something stupid that I didn't see... If you check closely the if(file_exists) you can see that the stmt is inside it and well... there wasn't an else to upload so if an image was unique nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really was something stupid that I didn't see as I mentioned in my comment above... If you check closely the if(file_exists) you can see that the stmt is inside it and well... there wasn't an else to upload so if an image was unique nothing happened so I just coppied the move_uploaded_file and the rest and added an else{ and that fixed the issue.

```
if (isset ($_POST['image'])) {
    $cust_id = $_POST['id'];
    $images = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $imageSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

if (!is_dir('img/logotipa/'.$cust_id)){
    mkdir('img/logotipa/'.$cust_id, 0777, true);
}

$upload_dir = 'img/logo/'.$cust_id.'/';
$imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($images,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
$up_image = $images;

if (file_exists($upload_dir.$images)){
    $counter = 0;
    
    while (file_exists($upload_dir.$up_image)){
        $up_image = $counter.'_'.$images;
        $counter++;            
    }

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir.$images);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO logos(customer_id, logo) VALUES (:ucid, :upic)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':ucid', $cust_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':upic',  $up_image);

    if ($stmt->execute()){
        echo '<script>window.location.href = "customer_logo.php";</script>';
    
    }
}else{
move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir.$images);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO logos(customer_id, logo) VALUES (:ucid, :upic)');
        $stmt->bindP

aram(':ucid', $cust_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':upic',  $up_image);

    if ($stmt->execute()){
        echo '<script>window.location.href = "customer_logo.php";</script>';
    
    }
}
```